# Ta-Feng dataset - Item Description

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

In the Ta-Feng Grocery Store dataset, does it even exist an description of the items? Just having the itemID's won't give you meaningful results.

Is there any other grocery store dataset that actually contains item descriptions?

This is the Ta-Feng dataset by the way: [Ta-Feng dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014904/download-link-for-ta-feng-grocery-dataset)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have this particular dataset, but according to [here](http://crono.dei.unipd.it/~dm/DATASETS/grocerymarket.htm), there is an attribute called 'Product Subclass' that would categorize the items to some degree.  There is no product name in the dataset.

Other grocery datasets may be more suitable for you [here](http://recsyswiki.com/wiki/Grocery_shopping_datasets).

Hope this Helps!

Comment: I guess that's the "category", but even that is just marked with a ID and nothing readable :(

Comment: I'm afraid you get what you're given.  I'm sorry that it doesn't give what you are looking for :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Its true. Product descriptions are not in the data set. Only Product ID exists. I would like to recommend "**foodmarkt dataset**" which could be downloaded from this link below.

```
https://sites.google.com/a/dlpage.phi-integration.com/pentaho/mondrian/mysql-foodmart-database/foodmart_mysql.tar.gz?attredirects=0
```

Comment: There is no market-basket transaction table in that dataset, is there?

Comment: @user3667569 it is there ... check sales_1998 table.. There you can find details